# Best way to overload / override isEmpty() for generic type attribute

Tags: java, oop, overriding, overloading

I want to check whether the "myfield" attribute is empty or not.

First, I tried below code segment. But it always call Object type method. and It returned wrong answer for list type objects (Collections)

```
public class Validator{

private T myField;
....
...

public boolean isEmptyCheck(){
    return isEmpty(myField);
}

private boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> coll){
    return coll.isEmpty();
}

private boolean isEmpty(Object obj){
    return obj.toString().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Then I tried below code segment using the instance of method.

```
public class Validator{

private T myField;
.....
....

public boolean isEmptyCheck(){

    if (myField instance of Collection<?>){
        retrun (Collection)myField.isEmpty();
    }
    else
        return myField.toString().isEmpty();
    }

}
```

It is working correctly. But as I know, the instance of method is not a good practice for OOP base projects. I want to know is there any other better solution for this scenario? If not, what can I do to improve this solution?

Comment: `toString` from `Object` just says 'a string representation of the object'.  There's no promise that an 'empty Object' will return an 'empty `String`' for it.  I'd be tempted to better know what you define 'empty' to mean for (for example) something which _isn't_ a `String` or a `Collection` (or `Array` or `Map` or anything else where it has a well defined meaning).

Comment: when empty String -> "", and when collection like list -> new ArrayList<>() empty list are needed to check

Comment: The proper solution may well just be _not_ to make this generic.  Have a different validator for different types.

Comment: As Louis Wasserman says, having two different ones is probably simpler.  Unfortunately, if you need to support arrays too you either need one for every primitive array type as well, or to simply accept `Object` and deal with the `instanceof` checks.